# Dependency assemblies not found on MacOS despite the "additionalProbingPaths" are set

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

***#UPD**: Solved.*

I have my .NetCore 2.1 app with some referenced dlls are not placed at common place. So I've added a `runtimeconfig.template.json` file to the project with such content:

```
{
    "additionalProbingPaths": [
        "NameOfSubfolderWithDlls"
    ]
}
```

It causes the `MyAppName.runtimeconfig.json` (with this block in it) to be produced when building the project.
And it does its work good - When I run the app on Windows, dlls are found.

BUT! when I try to run my app on MacOS, it looks like dotnet on Mac ignores (or doesn't see) the `MyAppName.runtimeconfig.json`, because I got this error:

```
An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (MyAppName.deps.json) was not found
```

Please, help to figure out, what is the reason of the problem?

Comment: PS: as experiment, I've updated my app from .NetCore 2.1 to .Net 5.0 (and installed .Net 5 on Mac) - it didn't affected the problem

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. Actually the problem was not in MacOS specificity. But just in a different way the "current dirrectory" env.variable was set (coincidentally the way was different on my Windows & Mac machines). And as "additionalProbingPaths"

> let you specify a relative path, but it's resolved based on the
> current directory, not the app directory. So it can point to random
> places depending on how the app is started.

(from here: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/48792#issuecomment-801913304)
, so dotnet searched for my additional dlls in some wierd place.